# Specific Numbering in Word to Text (Microsoft Visual Basic)

Tags: ms-word

I can use this:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

but this is not what I want to convert my numbering to text.

I have something like this:

```
Table 1. 
ART1 | List item |
ART2 | List item |

Table 2. 
 ART3 | List item |
 ART4 | List item |

Table 3. 
 ART5 | List item |
 ART6 | List item |
```

What I want is to convert the numbering "ART1-ART6" to text.
This is currently a numbering.

How do I go about this?

Much appreciated it.

Comment: «How do I go about this?» What have you tried? Clearly, if you want to convert only paragraphs that meet a certain condition, you need to have some code that can identify those paragraphs. For example, if they're formatting with a particular Style, you might use a Find for all paragraphs based on that Style; otherwise you might need to loop through all paragraphs and test their liststrings.

Comment: You can do this with a custom numbered list. This does not involve programming. See this thread on SuperUser and follow the steps provided in the answer. https://superuser.com/questions/1619158/create-multi-character-text-bullet-as-part-of-ms-word-style-definition/1619710#1619710